# Use $validators on blur/focus events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Now, in my validation directive I set validation state 'manually', like this:

```
$element.on('focus', function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
       ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('length', true);
    });
 });

 $element.on('blur', function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        if (ngModelCtrl.$modelValue && ngModelCtrl.$modelValue.length === +$attrs.maxlength) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('length', true);
        }      
        else if (ngModelCtrl.$modelValue.length < +$attrs.maxlength && ngModelCtrl.$modelValue.length > 0) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('length', false);
        }
     }
 });
```

But I want to set validation states with `$validators` with saving validation behaviour (on blur/focus events).

I can't use `ng-model-options` with `updateOn: 'blur'`.

Is other options to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `ngModel.$validators`?

Comment: I want to use `ngModel.$validators`, but I don't know how I can repeat same validation behaviour. I need some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to use a custom validator you will need to structure your directive a little differently.  The major difference is you need to require `ngModel`.

**Directive**

```
return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        // Run validator for maxLenth
        ngModel.$validators.customMaxLength = function(value) { 
          var status = false;
            if(value.length <= attrs.maxLengthValidator) {
              console.log(attrs.maxLengthValidator);
            status = true;
          }
              return status;
        };
    }
  }
```

Something important to note.  If you are using an attribute to do your validate against and the value can change you need to watch the value and run your validator function against in manually.  Because the model does not change the validator would not fire automatically.

**Add the following to the directive**

```
    scope.$watch(function() {
        return attrs.maxLengthValidator;    
    },function() {
        ngModel.$validate();
    });
```

If you validator returns false you form will automatically have `$valid` set to `false`

**HTML**

In the example below I use angular-messages to display the valid output.  This is an optional module that needs included.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':myForm.testField.$invalid}">
      <label class="control-label" for="testInput">Test Field</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="testField"  
        max-length-validator="3" required ng-model="testField"/>
    </div>
</form>

    <div ng-messages ng-messages-multiple class="bg-danger" for="myForm.testField.$error">
                <div ng-message when="required">Please enter value</div>
                <div ng-message when="customMaxLength">To Long</div>
    </div>
```

[Custom Validator Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rehEoyqsgVcX1Iv0J634)

---

### In regards to your question about firing the validator on blur

You don't really want to update the ngModel if the model value is invalid.

What I would recommend is using styles and a focus attribute with the field to toggle the display based on the focus of the field.

**Add something like the following to your input field**

```
ng-focus="myForm.testField.focus=true" ng-blur="myForm.testField.focus=false"
```

Then use checks with `ng-class`, `ng-show` or `ng-hide` to update your display.

*This has been added to the plnkr*

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks! But, could you update your plnkr with example of blur/focus validation? Then I can accept.

Comment: @Salasar, Are you are looking to only display the error when they leave the field?

Comment: Malkus, yes and I want to hide it if the field get focus

Comment: @Salasar, I updated the answer to help you with more with your specific question

Comment: Malkus, it is the proper answer, thank you very much!